What are the different ways to generate documentation (pdf or xml) based on camel routes
I went through 2 methods, the first being with PlantUML which I did not manage to make it work, and the second being the Quarkus Camel Hawtio plugin which works. But the two do not do documentation based on the highway code DSL Java, but rather via JMX during the Run.
And what comes out is just a diagram that is not very easily readable.
Isn't there a plugin/tool ​​that allows you to create real documentation based on the route code DSL java of a file? which at the output will summarize the route, then could detail endpoint by endpoint from From until the final TO. write a PDF or XML or Text or better HTML.
with the list of Components used (ftp, rest, file, cxf, etc.), DataFormat used...
thanks in advance.
